# Scroll Issue on Navigating to new Route

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-router

When I navigate to a new route from my existing route, my new page does not opens at top.

I have already tried many options.
This is one of the solution I found, but it didnt work for me.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    constructor(private router: Router, private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
          if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
          }
          console.log(evt)
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
        });
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different solution this worked for me

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private router: Router, private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      // Change height:100% into auto
      $('body').css('height', 'auto');
      // Successfully scroll back to top
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
      // Remove javascript added styles
      $('body').css('height', '');
      this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using this one option in App.component.ts:

```
router.events.pairwise().subscribe((event: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
      if (event[0] instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          window.scroll(0, 0);
      }
});
```

Option 2:

Angular 6.1 has the support of

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

Comment: I am currently working on Angular5, so I think, I will try your option 1

Comment: We are using this code in our app. its working for us. Try to add the code in app.component.ts constructor method

Comment: It is similar to what I have added in my question which was not working for me because of some CSS class